# CSS: Rearranging div elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have multiple `<div>` tag with same `width` but different `height` in a container. When the browser is `resized` and `<div>` elements are rearranged, they get a lot of spaces between. For example the following HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box">
        This has less height
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        This has more height
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        This has less height.
    </div>
</div>
```

Now when the browser is resized, the last div will move to the left side below the first div, but there's empty space between them because the middle div has more height. Please look at the image.

[image]
Is it possible to arrange these divs using pure CSS? I could not find a way, so I tried jQuery `masonry plugin`, that works ok but the problem is that it often does not resonse quickly (for example, when you open the page first time, the layout is totally messed up, but if you refresh the page it gets fine).

So if its not possible with CSS only, is there any way to make it work without complicated plugins (for example using jQuery only?)

**jsFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/HS2Zh/

Comment: how do you want to arrange the divs on resize? Stay in their initial position or reflow according to the new width? 

If you want to reflow then float is the only css-way to do it giving you the well-known side effect you are experiencing.

Comment: yes, i want to reflow them, but want to remove the empty space as shown in above example. Is there any simple jQuery way to do that if its not possible with CSS?

Comment: If you're using Masonry and load much content, with Ajax or whatever, you can simply trigger Masonry on window load, not on document ready; or you can fade Masonry's #container in after your content has loaded. Your jsfiddle loads instantly, so one would have to see your online sandbox in order to see what's happening when and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your questing is to remove the gap, you can remove this by using this code

```
            var h = 0;
            $('.box').each(function() 
            { 
                h = Math.max(h, $(this).height()); 
            }).height(h);
```

It will assign the unique height(max height of .box) to all .box classes

Comment: This wont solve the problem, cos this will make the smaller div height equal to larger div, there will be space anyway (now the space will be part of smaller div).

Answer (score 0):

That can be done by using jquery masonry plugin. Hope this link helps you http://masonry.desandro.com/

If you are using the plugin already then try to give some gap between the blocks so that it will be having free space to flow around